# Playframework does not show Form tag : Scala

Tags: html, forms, scala, playframework-2.2

I am trying to follow play framework tutorial, which can see in 'localhost:9000'.

As it says, I Edited file and compile but it does not show the result that I expected.
Follow is what I have done.

1. make play project in console(command : play new alpha)
2. then I ran that (move 'alpha' directory and play run)
3. make an folder named 'models' at /alpha/app/controllers.
4. Edit Application.scala

   ```
   package controllers

   import play.api._ 
   import play.api.mvc._ 
   import play.api.data._ 
   import play.api.data.Forms._

   import models.Task

   object Application extends Controller {

     val taskForm = Form("label" -> nonEmptyText)

     def index = Action {
       //Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
       //Ok("Let's Play!")
       Redirect(routes.Application.tasks)   }

     def tasks = Action {
       Ok(views.html.index(Task.all(), taskForm))   }   def newTask = Action { implicit request =>
       taskForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
         errors => BadRequest(views.html.index(Task.all(), errors)),
         label => {
           Task.create(label)
           Redirect(routes.Application.tasks)
         }
       )   
     }   def deleteTask(id: Long) = TODO 
   }
   ```
5. make /alpha/controllers/models/Task.scala

   ```
   package models

   case class Task(id: Long, label: String)

   object Task {   
     def all(): List[Task] = Nil   
     def create(label: String) {}   
     def delete(id: Long){} 
   }
   ```
6. finally I edited /alpha/conf/routes

   > ```
   > # Routes
   > # This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
   > # ~~~~
   >
   > # Home page
   > GET     /                           controllers.Application.index
   >
   > # Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
   > GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
   >
   > #Tasks
   > GET     /tasks                  controllers.Application.tasks
   > POST    /tasks                  controllers.Application.newTask
   > POST    /tasks/:id/delete       controllers.Application.deleteTask(id: Long)
   > ```
7. then I ran. I expected a form area and a button 'create'. Button is fine while Form does not. I got some messages instead of the form. below is that message.

   > BaseScalaTemplate(play.api.templates.HtmlFormat$@6435477c)
   >   (taskForm("label"))

I can not track this, because it was not an error. Is there any clue to fix this bugs? If you give a solution or clue that would be very appreciated :D

========== Thanks for share my problem ======================

[ index.scala.html ]

```
> @* Comment : @(message: String) *@ @(task: List[Task], taskForm:
> Form[String]) @import helper._
> 
> @main("Todo list") {
> 
>   <h1>@task.size task(s)</h1>
> 
>   <ul>
>     @task.map { task =>
>       <li>
>         @task.label
> 
>         @form(routes.Application.deleteTask(task.id)) {
>           <input type="submit" value="Delete">
>         }
>       </li>
>     }   </ul>
> 
>   <h2>Add a new task</h2>
> 
>   @form(routes.Application.newTask) {
>     @inputText (taskForm("label"))
>     <input type="submit" value="Create">   } }
```

Comment: Please, include your index.scala.html

Comment: Can you show your view template, where the form is used? (I believe it's index.scala.html). 

Note: models should be located directly in app/ folder, not in controllers/

Comment: @vitalii, britva I edited my post so that you can see index.scala.html now. When considering button which expressed normal, I assume there is no problem in magic keyword '@'.

Comment: I think maybe an error could be @inputText. When I make that phrase as comment(@* *@), No message("BaseScalaTemplate(....") printed. But I stil do not know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. It is really disappointed:-( 
There is an white space between @inputText and parameters.

It should be :

```
@inputText (taskForm("label")) -- change to --> @inputText(taskForm("label"))
```

Anyway, thanks for help :D